# Invalid Entitlement itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes

I get the following error when i try to install iPhone application via iTunes:

Entitlement are not valid.

What is the possible cause for this error? and how can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove provissioning Profile From iTunes, and generate new one,then add it to iTunes,  then add entitlement file to iTunes, it should works